# How to keep selected item in listview when new items are added?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, items

I am trying to make an application that lets me Check items in the ListView, and that all works fine, BUT if I add more items to the ListView while items are checked. It unchecks them all because the ListView is reloaded. Is there a way to get around this? So all of my items stay checked even when I add new ones to it? This is my current code.

```
            TextReader reader = new StringReader(richTextBox1.Text);
            string[] strItems = null;
            foreach (ListViewItem items in listView1.Items)
            {
                items.Remove();
            }
            while (reader.Peek() != -1)
            {
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
                strItems = reader.ReadLine().Split("-".ToCharArray());
                item.Text = strItems[0].ToString();
                item.SubItems.Add(strItems[1].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(strItems[2].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(strItems[3].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(strItems[4].ToString());
                listView1.Items.Add(item);
            }
```

Comment: IF you are reloading it, of course it will delete the checks. There is no state save to avoid it, you will have to construct it by yourself (or don't clear it, and just add the new items)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like that (and improve it a little by finding a better tag / exist logic):

```
        TextReader reader = new StringReader(richTextBox1.Text);
        string[] strItems = null;
        while (reader.Peek() != -1)
        {
            string nextRow = reader.ReadLine();
            if (!listView1.Items.ContainsKey(nextRow.GetHashCode().ToString()))
            {
               ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
               item.Name = nextRow.GetHashCode().ToString();
               strItems = nextRow .Split("-".ToCharArray());
               item.Text = strItems[0].ToString();
               item.SubItems.Add(strItems[1].ToString());
               item.SubItems.Add(strItems[2].ToString());
               item.SubItems.Add(strItems[3].ToString());
               item.SubItems.Add(strItems[4].ToString());
               listView1.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
```

The only problem with that is if you are trying to delete items that won't be in the new read strings, but you can solve it too (tell me if you need it and i will add it)

Comment: When doing this I get the error "'System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ListViewItemCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Exists' and no extension method 'Exists' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ListViewItemCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: try: !listView1.Items.ToList().Exists(item => item.Tag == nextRow)
it is not good for performance, but i just want to know if eventually that does the job for you

Comment: ToList() cannot be used after .Items apparently as it won't let me use it.

Comment: It doesn't work entirely this prevents me from adding new items to the ListView I am trying to figure out a way where it will keep all of the currently checked items checked even when I add more items to the listbox, But thanks for the help so far :)

Comment: I don't understand... it should add new items too, only not duplicates... do you want to have duplicate values?

Comment: No I don't that is the problem I don't want duplicates. It doesn't let me add items, but it doesnt uncheck the current ones either. I have a textbox that I enter items into then press a button to add them to the listview. It works the first time I do it, but it won't let me type extra items into the textbox and add them to the listview when I do that nothing changes. No items are unchecked, removed, or added.

Comment: Can you decide? in your question you wrote "It unchecks them all" as a bad thing, and now you write "but it doesnt uncheck the current ones either"... you got me confused

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12214/discussion-between-eyossi-and-ian-lundberg)